# Hibernate 5.2 Spring 4.3 MappingException: Could not determine type for: sun.security.util.Password

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to launch my Hibernate project but because one of the attribute fields in my Customer class is of type Password, the project won't launch cause it can't create a Db Column out of it.

I've tried annotating the Password field with `@Column(columnDefinition="varchar(20)")` above the attribute field, and above the getter but both didn't help.

Any clues anyone?

Here's the class:

```
package be.mobyus.ie5.entities;


import sun.security.util.Password;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
private Long id;
private String username;

private Password password;
private String name;
private String firstName;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Order.class, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Order> orders;

/***********************************************/

    public Customer(){

    }

    /***********************************************/


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(columnDefinition = "character varying(22)")
    public Password getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(Password password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Collection<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Collection<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: sun.security.util.Password, at table: Customer, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(password)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at be.mobyus.ie5.SpringRunner.main(SpringRunner.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: sun.security.util.Password, at table: Customer, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(password)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apparently use the Base64Util from the spring framework to encrypt/decrypt the Password attribute and store it as a varchar in the DB